# DataTable Render with ScrollY (table body is getting resized but thead is not getting resized)

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable, adminlte

am using datatables and also adding ScrollY into it... so when i have a lot of column that my screen can't fit all of it, it will just add vertical scroll in datatables form.... and the problem is adminlte have a feature that can hide and show sidebar and it will change overall area of datatables and in the result it will render wrong just like this:

my table body is getting resized but thead is not getting resized

This is a test link to my temporary page
https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/farazGreen/DataTable/blob/master/GreenBow_%20TEST.html

Same question has been asked by another person in ADMINLTE site
https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/issues/1136

Comment: I have Create a GIT

[GIT Link](https://github.com/farazGreen/DataTable)

Answer (score 1):

I think the way I took was not very smart, but I couldn't find the option anyway.

First, by using the chrome dev.tool, I found related table layers that has very limited pixed width which defined by datatables.

Second, I gave the css width with force(!important) option.

```
<style>
    .dataTables_scrollHead {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    .dataTables_scrollHeadInner {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    .dataTable  {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
</style>
```

Anyway it works but I really want to find elegant solution.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `autoWidth` to `false`

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "autoWidth": false
} );
```

Or you can `resize()` table on window resize event

```
$(window).resize(function () {
            $("#example").resize();
});
```

> Edit

In my local pc this code working  only add `"autoWidth": false` and remove the `scrollY` or `"scrollY":""`

```
$('#tblOpWaiting').DataTable({
    "bFilter" : false,
    "ordering" : false,
    "scrollY" : "",
    "scrollCollapse" : true,
    responsive : true,
    "paging" : false,
    autoWidth:false
});
$('#tblOpConsulted').DataTable({
    "bFilter" : false,
    "ordering" : false,
    "scrollY" : "",
    "scrollCollapse" : true,
    responsive : true,
    "paging" : false,
    autoWidth:false
});
```

Comment: Please do check this link,
Window is not getting resized, it is a div which gets resized
and I tried autoWidth:false
also autoWidth:true

[Check This Link](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/farazGreen/DataTable/blob/master/GreenBow_%20TEST.html)

Comment: "paging" : false you have forgotten to put a comma ","

if you check your console window you can see the error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

so the datatable property did not get set.

try to put the comma, and see if it works.. It didnt work for me

Comment: @MunasirPv remove the `scrollY` then it's working fine

Comment: my question specifically tells that I want to get result with SCROLLY, i know that it will work very well without ScrollY, I do appreciate your willingness to help!